# define score limit for pylint with pre-commit git hook

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit

I am trying to set a accepted pylint score limit for my pre-commit git hook. I have tried two approaches:

A) adding it to the `.pylintrc` file

```
[pre-commit-hook]
command=custom_pylint
disable=E0401, C0301
limit=8.0
```

B) adding it as argument to `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
    rev: v2.12.2
    hooks:
      - id: pylint
        args:
          - --limit=7
          - --rcfile=./.pylintrc
```

Sadly for A, it just does not except it independent of the score. For B, I get the error, `pylint: error: no such option: --limit`.

Best regards

Comment: the option is `--fail-under` or `fail-under` -- not sure where you got `limit` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `--fail-under=7`, not `--limit` see [documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html?highlight=fail-under#general-options).

You can also read the output of `pylint --help`.